# Name XHTML element from XSLT for each position

Tags: xml, xslt, position

I have a select dropdown menu and a span which are referenced in a javascript file as 'quantity1', 'quantity2' and 'price1', 'price2', etc respectively.

In the XSLT, I need to be able to state the ID of this element as relative to the position for the  loop, but can't quite figure out how.

```
<span id="price<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>/>£<xsl:value-of select="price"/>">
```

This doesn't work (clearly!), socan anyone explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're creating the `<span>` element within the XSLT transformation you can use the [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) syntax. Like this:

```
<span id="price{position()}">£<xsl:value-of select="price"/></span>
```

the `<span>` would be created within the template or `xsl:for-each` construct for `position()` to give you what you expect.

You can also use a more verbose [xsl:attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes) construct with the `xsl:value-of` like you attempted originally:

```
<span>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">price<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
    £<xsl:value-of select="price"/>
</span>
```

The curly braces of the attribute value template look much better to my taste.